# Why does .post edit the max-width of my footer?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS so I am doing a online course, I don't understand what went wrong here and I cannot find it in my course.
My footer is smaller then it used to, it was as big as my header and  I want it as big as my header. When I added all the .post code, it went wrong. When I edit my .post max-width my footer width is also adjusted. Please help me :)

```
    .container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #footer {
      background-color: #2f2f2f;
      padding: 50px 0;

    }
    .column {
      min-width: 300px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;

    }
    #footer h4 {
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.1em
    }
    #footer p {
      color: white;

   .post {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 60px 0;
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, you are missing the closing brackets for your `#footer p` and `.post` classes. try adding them in and see what happens.

Comment: When I use the CSS on another page my footer isn't small again. Makes it more confusing than before for me x)

Comment: Hi. Please include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or, if it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to, then we would very much appreciate it. :)